# Modifying a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to multiply the number of characters that occur in each string in a list.

- Every string stored at an even index should be doubled.
- Every string stored at an index that is a multiple of 3 should be tripled.
- Every other string should remain unchanged.
- 0 should be counted in both the multiple of 2 and 3 category

Code:

```
def multiply_strings(myList):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(0,len(myList)):
        if myList[i] == 0:
            newlist.append((myList[i]*2)*3)
        if myList[i]%2== 0:
            newlist.append(myList[i]*2)
        if myList[i]%3 == 0:
            newlist.append(myList[i]*3)
        else:
            newlist.append(i)
    return newlist

test_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
print(multiply_strings(test_list))
```

It should be returning:

```
['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG']
```

However I am getting a type error that not all arguments are converted.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The elements of `myList` are characters but in your function you try and treat them as if they were numbers.

Comment: What are you trying to multiply them by? Your goal is not clear. For example, by what multiplicative logic is 'A' -> 'AAAAAA' and 'B' -> 'B'.

Comment: As the former comments mention: taking a modulu of a non-number generates an error.

Comment: @Lagerbaer in Python, multiplying strings by integer is allowed, i.e. `"a"*3 == "aaa"`

Comment: I have edited the question to increase clarity in what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @jurez Yes but you cannot use modulo on a string

Comment: @superbrain you're right (comment edited), strings can be multiplied, but you can't calc `%` of a string so my comment still stands.

Comment: @NirAlfasi I am using the % to see if the index is an even number or divisible by 3, can you advise how I might change this to reflect that?

Comment: @M46 you're not using modulo on the index (`i`) you're doing it on the list elements: `myList[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistakes are that

- `myList[i]%2` tries to modulo on a string, that's isn't possible wht you want is `i%2`
- use `elif` to avoid going in too much condition, like `0` is going into all of them

```
def multiply_strings(myList):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(0, len(myList)):
        if i % 2 == 0 and i % 3 == 0:
            newlist.append((myList[i] * 2) * 3)
        elif i % 2 == 0:
            newlist.append(myList[i] * 2)
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            newlist.append(myList[i] * 3)
        else:
            newlist.append(myList[i])
    return newlist
```

You can reduce to

```
def multiply_strings(myList):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(0, len(myList)):
        by_two = 2 if i % 2 == 0 else 1
        by_three = 3 if i % 3 == 0 else 1
        newlist.append(myList[i] * by_two * by_three)
    return newlist
```

Or even  that with a list comprehension

```
def multiply_strings(myList):
    return [myList[i] * (2 if i % 2 == 0 else 1) * (3 if i % 3 == 0 else 1) 
            for i in range(0, len(myList))]
```

Answer (score 1):

A perhaps simpler way (I like avoiding indices):

```
def multiply_strings(myList):
    for m in 2, 3:
        myList[::m] = [s * m for s in myList[::m]]
    return myList
```

Another, more like yours:

```
def multiply_strings(myList):
    newlist = []
    for i, s in enumerate(myList):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            s *= 2
        if i % 3 == 0:
            s *= 3
        newlist.append(s)
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 1):

You are modding the letters, while you should be modding the indices and basing your decisions on that.

```
for i in range(0,len(myList)):
    new_el = myList[i]
    if i % 3 == 0: new_el *= 3  # Every string stored at an index that is a multiple of 3 should be tripled.
    if i % 2 == 0: new_el *= 2  # Every string stored at an even index should be doubled.
    newlist.append(new_el)
```

Also, here's a for-fun one-liner:

```
return [v * max(1,(i%2==0)*2) * max(1,(i%3==0)*3) for i,v in enumerate(myList)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use modulo on a string.

I modified your code a bit to match your expected output

```
def multiply_strings(myList):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if i == 0:
            newlist.append((myList[i]*6))
        elif i%2 == 0:
            if i%3 == 0:
                newlist.append((myList[i]*2)*3)
            else:
                newlist.append(myList[i] * 2)
        elif i%3== 0:
            newlist.append(myList[i] * 3)
        else:
            newlist.append(myList[i])
    return newlist

test_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
print(multiply_strings(test_list))
```